# Get values in listbox2 which are in {X=0,Y=0} format in another listbox1

Tags: c#

I have defined this list in listBox1, values shown like this:

you can get these values in listbox1 with the help of this code as:

```
enter code here
```

namespace Form
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    public Form1()




    {
        InitializeComponent();



    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




    listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} , {1}", "{X=168", "Y=96}"));





    }
}
```

}

I want to convert these values to show like this in two lines in another listBox2.. in two indexes.

168

96

so to easily save in the array.

Comment: please format your post so its readable.  Code belongs in code blocks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Looks like you need to define a `ToString()` method for the `PointF` class

Comment: So why are you putting the values like this in the first place? Just add them as `Point`, and you can do whatever you want with the value afterwards.

Comment: how i can use these values.

Comment: In my software i m getting these values in this format so how i can use this.

Comment: these are the mouse click values when click on the pictureBox...

Comment: Help me about this..what can i do.

Comment: Finally,I got the answer...